# Bash Script - Scope of variables in while loop

Tags: bash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bash Script - Variable Scope in Do-While loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719548/bash-script-variable-scope-in-do-while-loop)

In the following code, it prints the correct value of `i` in inner while loop, but it prints 0 after it comes out of inner while loop:

```
string="Medicine"
for file in *
do
    i=0
    cat $file | while read line
    do
        echo $line
        if [ "$line" == "$string" ];
        then
            i=`expr $i + 1`
            echo $i
        fi
    done
    echo $i
done
```

Answer (score -2):

By default variables have global scope in shell scripting, which make "i " global. if you want to make a variable as local ,use keyword "local" , for eg: `local i=0`

for more details check the link, http://www.bashguru.com/2008/06/bash-variables-scope.html

Comment: It is an error to use `local` outside a function, and you completely ignore the fact that the while loop is running in a subshell, which is the source of the poster's problem.