# Grouping commands in curly braces and piping does not preserve variable

Tags: bash

Say I have a file `myfile` in my current working directory. I want to set a variable if a command executes normally, but also use its result.

```
$ ls myfile && v=3
myfile
$ echo "$v"
3
```

But now I also want to pipe the result, so I use the `{ list; }` syntax to group the commands:

```
$ unset v
$ { ls myfile && v=3; } | grep myf
myfile
$ echo "$v"
                  # v is not set
```

[Bash reference manual -> 3.2.4.3 Grouping Commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping) says:

> ```
> { list; }
> ```
>
> Placing a list of commands between curly braces causes the list to be
>   executed in the current shell context. No subshell is created. The
>   semicolon (or newline) following list is required.

So, to my understanding, `v` should be set to 3. But it is not happening. Why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not the curly braces that are causing a subshell to be created, it's the pipe.

To prove it:

```
$ { ls && v=3; } > tmp
$ echo "$v"
3
```

To quote [Greg](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024):

> In most shells, each command of a pipeline is executed in a separate SubShell.

Comment: Ooooh, so `v=1 | echo "hi"` would be the same case.

Comment: Yes, the change to `v` would only last for the lifetime of the subshell.

Comment: True, because `v=2; v=1 | echo "hi, v=$v"` return "hi, v=2". Interesting, many thanks!

Comment: @fedorqui Look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30458681/bash-piping-output-from-a-loop-seems-to-change-the-scope-within-the-loop-why/30459206#30459206). It's pretty much the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`BASH_SUBSHELL`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Variables) variable to verify whether you're in subshell or not.

```
# BASH_SUBSHELL will print level of subshell from top due to pipe
{ unset v && ls file && v=3 && echo "$BASH_SUBSHELL - $v"; } | nl
     1  file
     2  1 - 3

# outside BASH_SUBSHELL will print 0
echo "$BASH_SUBSHELL - $v";
0 -
```

You can use for piped command it prints `1` meaning it is in a subshell hence value of `v` isn't available outside (evident from 2nd output)

Comment: Thanks for the trick, anubhava, you always come with some interesting stuff : )

Comment: $BASHPID can also be used to get the real PID of the shell instance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `read` and curly braces to do what you want:

```
ls myfile && echo success | { read result; echo $result; }
```

Here's more about why: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/338000/bash-assign-output-of-pipe-to-a-variable